How to change the circle color of Slider of SwiftUI?
I am trying to change the color of the circle of the SwiftUI Slider. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find a way. I am sharing the code I did till now. and also the screenshot of the view. I don't want to use UIKit Slider in my SwiftUI view. I appreciate any help and suggestions.
  Slider(
                value: $lightIntensity,
                in: 1...5,
                step: 2
            ) {
                /// Used for accessibility 
                Text(R.string.localized.settings_appliancedetail_button_interior_light())
            }
        onEditingChanged: { editing in
                isEditing = editing
            }
        .accentColor(R.color.primary.color)

Here is the screenshot of the view:

So all I want is to change the white circle color to primary color.

You could try this approach using UISlider.appearance():
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var lightIntensity: Float

    init(lightIntensity: Binding<Float>) {
        self._lightIntensity = lightIntensity

        UISlider.appearance().thumbTintColor = R.color.primary.color //<- here
    }
}


Thanks, it works. And I didn't have to bring back the UIKit slider.

You can use an overlay to cover the button quite effectively:
let minLightIntensity = 1.0
let maxLightIntensity = 5.0

Slider(/* as before */) {
    //...
}
.accentColor(R.color.primary.color)
.overlay {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        let w = proxy.size.width
        let h = proxy.size.height
        Circle()
            .fill(R.color.primary.color)
            .offset(x: (lightIntensity - minLightIntensity) * (w - h) / (maxLightIntensity - minLightIntensity))
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
    }
}

With this approach, you can change the appearance of the button in more ways than just the color. For example, you can use a different shape, or show a symbol over the button.
